# How to generate a input type dropdown using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Hi I am using codeigniter. I am adding row dynamically using javascript when button is clicked.
Here is my script

```
<script>
function displayResult() {
    var row = document.getElementById("test").insertRow(-1);
    row.innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" name="employee[]" value="" style="width:80px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="pid[]" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="type" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty_prch" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty_used" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td>';
}
</script>
```

Here in this script I am generating a row with many textbox. Now I need to have a `form_dropdown` instead of the first text box in the script(`employee[]`)
My form_dropdown code:
Here I get the data from the controller file. I have this employee detail in my database

```
<?php
      //form data
      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
      $options_employee = array('' => "Select");
      foreach ($employee as $row)
      {
        $options_employee[$row['name']] = $row['name'];
      }

      ?>
```

This is how I use it in view page.

```
<?php
          echo '<div class="control-group">';

            echo '<div class="controls">';

              echo form_dropdown('employee', $options_employee, set_value('employee[]'), 'class="span2"');

            echo '</div>';
          echo '</div">';

          ?>
```

How to do this can someone help me code? 
**Edit 01:**
[image]

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: I need a dropdown inside javascript.I dynamically add row using javascript. now I need form_dropdown instead of a text box. normal form_dropdown works fine. Now how could I insert them dynamically

Comment: So once the page gets loaded you are getting dropdown and now you want to add new option in dropdown using javascript from the textbox. Is this what you mean to say??

Comment: Please take a look at my post. I added a image. There I have a add row button when I click it I create another row similar to it. Now instead of first text box i need a dropdown. I add a new row using javascript. I do not no how to have a dropdown here

Comment: This might be the simplest implementation to do this: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery

Comment: Once you get this right I will show you how to change textbox into dropdown.

Comment: That was helpful then how to change it as dfopdown?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90029/discussion-between-indrasinh-bihola-and-anu).

Comment: can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Dropdowns are really easy in JS when you have the data array.

You can use the JS native map function with arrays to easily render menus like the following.

**JSON/Object:**

```
$options_employee: [
  'Michael',
  'John',
  'Sam'
]
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="employee-menu">
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <select name="employee" class="span2">
        <option></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
mag.module("employee-menu", {
  view: function(state, props) {
    state.option = props.$options_employee.map(function(employee, key) {
      return {
        _value: key,
        _text: employee
      }
    })
  }
}, props)
```

Here is the full working example: http://jsbin.com/pexifodari/edit?html,js,output

Hope that helps!

Comment: I cant have a html code. I need to have dropdown inside javascript